# Does Paypal Provide the Paypal Rest API for direct debit card API?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I need API of Direct Debit PayPal like Direct Credit Card. How can I get that. I search it on Google, but I hadn't got any answer from them. So much confused about that matter.So anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better switch to ccavaneue if you are focusing to target domestic bank debit cards.

Comment: instead of google, have you tried the actual paypal doc's? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/

Answer (score 1):

The method of payment depends from the country.
I think debit card is available for the UK.
If you check the documentation here
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/

"What countries does PayPal support?

The REST API supports a number of countries and currencies. To check REST API support for direct credit card payments for a US account, see the Account eligibility page. Direct credit card support in the REST API is available in the UK if you sign up for a UK Website Payments Pro account"